# Displaying form reults on the confirmation page

Tags: php, html, server-side-includes

I have a simple html form.

```
<form name="cmxform" method="post" action="projecthandler.php" id="doxform"> 

<tr>

    <td><input name="firstname" type="text" size="40"></font></td>
  </tr>
<tr>

</tr>
<tr>

    <td><input name="lastname" type="text" size="40"></td>
  </tr>
</form>
```

And the projecthandler.php scrpit sends email to user

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['firstname'])) {

   $email_to = "shruti15sargam@gmail.com";
   $email_subject = "Project Subject";
   $email_subject_user = "Confirmation";

    $firstname = $_POST['firstname']; // required

    $lastname = $_POST['lastname']; // required




    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";
    $email_message_user = "Thank you....";



    function clean_string($string) {

      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

    }



    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($firstname)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($lastname)."\n";





// create email headers

$headers = 'From: '.$Email."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();


mail($Email, $email_subject_user, $email_message, 'From: donotreply@somemail.edu');
header('Location: thanks.html');


?>



 <div>
echo "Hello World";
        </div>
```

The final thanks.html page needs to display these first and last name values on it as form data.  How can I echo the results from this form to the confirmation(thanks.html) page.
Thanks.

Comment: Assuming you have a submit button? It won't submit on its own. If you have one, include it in your question/code.

Comment: To answer your question, you basically can't using an `.html` extension unless you instruct Apache to treat `.html` files as PHP. Change it to `.php` and use sessions, which is by far more transportable than mere POST, when it comes to passing variables to multiple pages.

Comment: Yes, the form works just fine, I can email this form data just fine. The problem is to display these results on html file. How can I do that?

Comment: As I said in my second comment.

Comment: I tried making it a php page but then, I have includes for html headers, body and footer which are not working. I am so confused.

Comment: You're presently using `header('Location: thanks.html');` just change it to `header('Location: thanks.php');` and use sessions. You assign it to a variable from POST then to the session name.

Comment: okay, I need to see some examples of session and I'll try this. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Have a look at this sessions tutorial, it's very well-written => http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-To-PHP-Sessions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either send the values in the url www.mydomain.co.uk?value1=val&value2=val2

and then get the data from there (assuming you are okay with this security wise). Or like it has already been mentioned you could set session values:

ie:

```
<?php

session_start();
$_SESSION['value1'] = $val;
$_SESSION['value2'] = $val2;
```

sessions are probably the way to go tbh.